# What happens if I have two versions of a workflow.yaml in main (master) and another branch?

Tags: github-actions

I have `workflow1.yml`  in my main (master) brach.

I have an updated version of the workflow.yaml. file in two another branches (3 version of the file in total)

Is there any way to define which branch is the source of `workflow1.yml` so runner run the code from a diffrent brach instead of the one in the master brach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow yml file which is run will be the one found in the commit triggering the event.

See "[Example using multiple events with activity types or configuration](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#example-using-multiple-events-with-activity-types-or-configuration)"

> The `.github/workflows` directory in your repository is searched for workflow files at the associated commit SHA or Git ref. The workflow files must be present in that commit SHA or Git ref to be considered.
>
> For example, if the event occurred on a particular repository branch, then the workflow files must be present in the repository on that branch.

So if an event occurs on a particular branch, the `workflow.yaml` present in that branch will run.